# How to convert hex 'YMD' date to a readable date?

Tags: sql, date, hex

I've been given a file with a bunch of dates inside.  They're in Hex format and I'm told it's YMD.

Example is: 4A273F

..any idea how I'd go about converting it?  Idealling using SQL/PLSQL but I'm open to other ideas.

thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other information on the encoding used, or an example of date value for which you already know the answer?

Comment: It can't be converted without knowing what it represents. If it's YMD how is it broken up? 4A = 74 (1974?) as year, but 27 = 39 which can't be month. If it's a whole number (4A273F = 4859711) it's only 26 Feb 1970 if treated as a Unix epoch datestamp.

Comment: Sorry all .. I had hoped it'd be a standard format :(

Comment: Another sample: 4A 3D 41 .. I'm pretty sure that should convert to 17th Nov 2003.  Hope that helps! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Oracle and java play fairly well with each other, and this is may be a new idea if you're feeling adventerous.  Java does this pretty easily, but i'm away from an oracle box and unable to test.  This really hurts i'm not in front of an oracle machine at the moment.  To make sure I remembered correctly, I used steps from here
 http://www.dba-oracle.com/tips_oracle_sqlj_loadjava.htm

and then I googled this, which is almost word for word what we'll do below:
http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/guide8i/ch09_03.htm

```
/****
*java and oracle playing together.
 */
import java.util.Date;
public class hex2Date{
   //this is if you want to call the java function from a command line outside of oracle
     public static void main (String args[]) {
         System.out.println ( convert (args[0]) );    
    }

     public static Date convert(String inHexString){
       try{
        Date dateResult = new Date(Long.parseLong(inHexString,16));
       }catch (NumberFormatException e){
       // do something with the exception if you want, recommend at least throwing it.
    //throw(e,'some extra message');

       }

        return dateResult;
   }
}
```

save that file as Hex2Date.java in 'yourJava' directory, and from a cmd line in that directory type:

javac Hex2Date.java

now type:

java Hex2Date.java 0x4A273F

if you get the right dates, and the results, let's tell oracle about our little function. 
you'll need some user rights first:
GRANT JAVAUSERPRIV TO your user here;
type this:
loadjava -user scott/tiger -resolve Hex2Date.class

now wrap this in pl/sql, so you can call it in pl/sql.:

```
/* java function plsql wrapper: hex2Date.sf */ 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hex2Date (    inHexString IN VARCHAR2)     RETURN DATE AS LANGUAGE JAVA    NAME 'Hex2Date.convert(java.lang.String)              return Date'; /
```

now, run it from a sql prompt:
SQL> exec DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (        hex2Date('0x4A273F'))

Comment: haha, use this if you want, but i read the rest of the posts and realized this will still have an issue with the 'YMD' format. you would need to hack the 'inHexString' in the convert() function. translating the year, month, and day to milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess they are unix dates? I'd also guess that by **SQL**/PLSQL you have access to SQL Server and Oracle? If my guesses are both right I'd use SQL Server's convert function:

select convert(int, 0x4A273F)

As well as its date add function (start from Jan 1, 1970 and add seconds):

select dateadd(ss, {your_result}, '19700101')

Of course if they are all in csv files, a script might do just as well. Do you have anymore information?

Comment: I just posted another sample above:
 4A 3D 41 .. I'm pretty sure that should convert to 17th Nov 2003
Thanks!

Comment: Can you give at least one more example (more if you have them) to get a comparison, to see what changes?

Comment: Annoyingly samples are a bit scarce but I found one more:
50 34 2E is 27th April 2009.  Thanks!

Comment: If you subtract 4A from 50 you get 6 which happens to be the difference between 2003 and 2009. So perhaps the year is simply adding the first part to 1929 (or x789)

Comment: The problem is that the rest of the numbers don't make sense. Even when piecing them out, I just can't get the differences to add up. Good luck! Were these files from a mainframe?

Answer (score 0):

If the 'HEX' values are from a Mainframe, then perhaps they are EBCDIC (Extended Binary Coded Decimal Interchange Code) and not HEX? I don't have time to reason it out right now but try this page for ideas/clues? http://www.simotime.com/asc2ebc1.htm  Of course I may be barking up the wrong tree :)

Assume 50 34 2E is 27th April 2009

```
EBCDIC HEX DEC
5      F5  245
0      F0  240
3      F3  243
4      F4  244
2      F2  242
E      C5  197
```